# EF returns "Cannot Insert NULL" ... But column defines a default value

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am Using EF 6, Database First (edmx), I have defined a table with a NON NULLABLE field which has a default value defined. When I use EF to insert a new record I am getting the error ...

```
"Cannot insert the value NULL into column attr_is_required ... "
```

Here's the table definition ...

```
CREATE TABLE [Auth].[AppAttributes]
(
    [app_attr_id]  BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    [app_id]       BIGINT NOT NULL, 
    [attr_name]    NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [attr_description] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL, 
    [attr_type]    NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,   
    [attr_is_required] BIT        DEFAULT (0) NOT NULL, 
    [created_date] DATETIME       DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
    [created_by]   NVARCHAR (50)  DEFAULT ('db') NOT NULL,
    [updated_date] DATETIME       DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
    [updated_by]   NVARCHAR (50)  DEFAULT ('db') NOT NULL, 
)
```

Here is the C# used to add the record. You will notice that I do not specify the **attr_is_required** at all.

```
uow.DbContext.AppAttributes.Add( new AppAttribute
{
    app_id           = adminApp.app_id,
    attr_description = "User's Date of Birth",
    attr_name        = "DateOfBirth",
    attr_type        = AppAttributeTypes.DATE.ToString(),
    created_by       = UnitTestSvc.CREATED_BY,
    created_date     = DateTime.Now,
    updated_by       = UnitTestSvc.UPDATED_BY,
    updated_date     = DateTime.Now
});
```

I have managed to log the SQL generated by EF.

```
INSERT [Auth].[AppAttributes]([app_id], [attr_name], [attr_description], [attr_type], [attr_is_required], [created_date], [created_by], [updated_date], [updated_by])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, NULL, @4, @5, @6, @7)
```

What I notice is that the NULL value is explicitly being assigned to the **attr_is_required** column. I read somewhere that removing this field from the INSERT statement would allow the default to be used instead. The problem is that the SQL generation is abstracted away by EF. I am not sure what, if anything there 
is I can do about this. I suppose I CAN explicitly provide the value if I have to, but it doesn't seem like I should be required to provide it.

Does anyone know a way to deal with this?

DUPLICATE?

The referrred to article is dealing with code-first approach where I am using database-first and the visual designer. That being said the article did inspire me to look at something which led me to an solution.

SOLUTION

In the visual designer (EDMX file) I selected the **attr_is_required** property on the **AppAttribute** object. In the properties pane I noticed the setting for "Nullable" Setting this to FALSE appears to have resolved my issue.

Comment: Your analysis is correct.  To get the Default value to be used you have to remove the field from the actual raw sql.  I am interested to learn what the best way to do this with EF6 is.

Comment: While I disagree with this being tagged as a duplicate, since the referred to post is dealing with code-first, and I am using database first approach with the visual designer (edmx) in VS, the post DID inspire me to look at the individual field Properties of the field in the EDMX file. I selected the **attr_is_required** field in the designer and in the properties pane I set the **Nullable** property to FALSE. This seems to have resolved the issue.

Comment: That seems like an appropriate error. Your table definition says the column can not be NULL so I would not expect you to be able to give it a NULL. Remove the column from the insert statement to have the default value applied.

Comment: Does Not Seem Like a Duplicate.  The so-called duplicate has a solution that uses the compiled code to define the default value.  The solution desired in this question is to respect the current default of the DB at runtime without requiring a hardcoded default in the compiled code.

Comment: @thomas The problem is that EF is auto-generating the INSERT statement and determining which columns to include. I would think that by not specifying ANY value for that field at all, it would not include it, but it does and provides it with a NULL value, thereby breaking the request. I am using the database-first approach and visual designer to avoid as much interaction with the EF details as possible. If I have to engage in custom coding in order to omit fields from the auto-generated SQL then I begin to lose much of the supposed value of this approach.